# Angular - how to avoid adding history when changing search?

Tags: angularjs

I have a property on the page that I would like to reflect on the URL in a specific page.

I have set `reloadOnSearch:false` for that page.

when the page loads it reads the `local storage` and if that property was saved, it will add its value to the search. However that adds a history record, so what I click `back` I get the url without that search parameters.

I need to avoid the double back presses.

Here is a snippet I made (I will try to make it run on plunkr)

my HTML file (snippet.html)

```
<html ng-app="snippet">
    <head>
        <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script src="snippet.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body ng-view="">

    </body>

</html>
```

my JavaScript file (snippet.js)

```
angular.module('snippet',['ngRoute']).config(function( $routeProvider ){
    $routeProvider.when('/so', {
        'template' : 'this is my template',
        'controller' : 'SnippetCtrl',
        'reloadOnSearch':false
    }).when('/first', {
        'template' : '<a href="snippet.html#/so">go here</a>'
    })
        .otherwise({
        redirectTo : '/first'
        // redirectTo: '/public/session/login'
    });
});


angular.module('snippet').controller('SnippetCtrl', function($location, $scope){

    $scope.name = 'guy';

    $location.search('hello','world')

});
```

- go to snippet.html
- location should change to `#/first`
- click on link
- location should change to `#/so` and then immediately to `#/so?hello=world`
- click back
- location change to `#/so` - ***I would like to avoid this***

Comment: can you add a snippet/jsfiddle/plunker?

Comment: I am not sure how to manipulate route in plunkr. but I will try to add a snippet

Comment: fork this: http://plnkr.co/edit/kHXK54?p=info

Comment: Thank you for the plunkr - I still cannot understand how to reproduce this issue with plunkr as it requires clicking `back`.

Comment: @JossefHarush I just read about `replace` for location. perhaps that will do.. I will try

Comment: @JossefHarush - I just tried. changing `$location.search('hello','world')` to `$location.search('hello','world').replace()` gets this affect for me.

Comment: Nice! :) BTW here's the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/iLCUv3PLB4GkHiI6r2eH?p=preview and this is how to run it: http://run.plnkr.co/KgZplPhppXsh561k/#/first

Comment: You should probably post your answer as an answer, not as part of the question. (Otherwise this is treated as an unanswered question).

Comment: @JossefHarush - wow! thanks! I can't believe you went through the trouble :) this is why I love stackoverflow, people care!

Comment: @MichalCharemza - sure. I was confused. I knew stackoverflow had a restriction for a minimum time but that was to accept my answer not writing it..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After 3 days of trial and error, and 10 minutes after I posted this question, I found the answer...

Instead of using $location.search(...) I should be doing $location.search(...).replace()

---

found my own q/a after 3.5 years.. #gottaLoveStackoverflow.. seems that in later versions of angular I had to split the calls.

```
 $location.search(...)
 $location.replace()
```

Chaining them produces an error.
And for the record, according to angular documentation

> If called, all changes to $location during the current $digest will replace the current history record, instead of adding a new one.

So use with care.